# How do I know what data I can access via an observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, object

I'm trying to use the sales_order_invoice_pay observer.

I can see the dispatch in:
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_invoice_pay', [$this->_eventObject => $this]);
```

Which seems to provide an invoice object?
But I'm having trouble accessing any properties or methods.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

returns nothing..

Generally speaking how do I find out what I can access via each observer?
There doesn't seem to be any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the top of the class for **/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php**, you can see the following code:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_eventObject = 'invoice';
```

Now you can able to get the value in the observer by

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
```

You have $invoice object, you can get the order from that. Like:

```
$order = $invoice->getOrder();
```